# Сворачивание программы

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, borland

Как сделать так, чтобы когда сворачивал программу она была на панели, где время? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот эффект достигается созданием/удалением иконки в области tray и скрытии/показе кнопки программы на taskbar'е.

- [Тут](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq.html) находится FAQ, судя по вопросам, не лишним будет ознакомиться.
- Ваш вопрос относится к faq по ["рабочему столу"](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/desktop.html).
- [Тут](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/tray_icon_example.html) исходник, решающий задачу.